# Java Junit repeat a repeating (or nest of repeating) test?

Tags: java, nested, junit5

The test are repeating in a multi dimensional like manner, would a hierarchy as follows be possible to implement with simplicity? I expect the UI, e.g. the VSC Testing UI to show nests of the sub-tests

```java
class Test {
    @RepeatedTest(...)
    class ChildTest {
        RepetitionInfo info = ...

        @RepeatedTest(...)
        public void test() {
            RepetitionInfo info2 = ...
            System.out.printf(..., info1.getCurrentRepetition(), info2.getCurrentRepetition());

            // Idea:

            // 0 - 0
            // 0 - 1
            // 0 - 2
            // ...

            // 1 - 0
            // 1 - 1
            // 1 - 2
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A general rule of unit testing is each test [tests a single assumption about the code.](https://horizontal.blog/2016/08/30/unit-testing-a-sample-approach/)  Large loops like this seem to violate that rule.  Can you par the test down to just one assumption?

Comment: There are a lot of test cases especially in combination: There are prime numbers and there are individual numbers. The idea is to write a 'combinator' of the primes and the numbers. (Would like to keep the hierarchy in the native test explorer ui of vsc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Junit5's `@Nested` annotation. This will allow a common setup of a group of tests and it will also show the test report very nicely in your IDE. You would be able to use it like so:

```java
class Test {
    // RepetitionInfo info1 = ... // will be available for all

    @Nested
    @RepeatedTest(...)
    class ChildTest {
        RepetitionInfo info2 = ... // will be available for this class only

        @RepeatedTest(...)
        public void test() {
           ... // you can use info1 + info2 here
        }
        @RepeatedTest(...)
        public void test2() {
           ... // you can use info1 + info2 here
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @RepeatedTest(...)
    class ChildTest3 {
        RepetitionInfo info3 = ... // will be available for this class only
        // ... // you can use info1 + info3
    }
}
```

If this is something you need, you can read more about it here:
https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-nested-test-classes

Comment: This didn't work for me, what versions of junit and java do you have?

Comment: junit5. what is the error? here are the official docs: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested
additionally, in the baeldung article you'll find a link to the source code